# is there a command to accelerate CPU?

Tags: cpu-speed, cpu-load

I'm running the code for object detection using OpenCV, the number of frames is not enough to move the robot smoothly. So, I'd like to accelerate the `CPU` more when the robot moves.

when we use jetson, this command `sudo ./jetson_clocks.sh` accelerate it to increase FPS (frame per second).

if there is any command please help.

this is output `top` when I run the code:

[image]

are there any issues if I use it?? you can see `load average: 5.68, 5.27, 4.21` is very hight.

Comment: DV for lack of research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You'll need to work on your code, or the code of OpenCV to see if you can improve it some how (i doubt it).

A load of 5 means your cpu's are loaded so much, that at the time there is 5 processes waiting for CPU time. The only 'easy' solution is to add more CPU, by either upgrading the CPU, or going to a system with more CPU cores.

Comment: Thanks, @djsmiley2k - CoW for the explanation,  another issue when running the same code on another computer 6 cores, the computer's sound goes up and down.  When goes up I observe a good performance. could you let me know the reason, please?